# request.user is false condition not working in template

Tags: python, django

Here's my template:

```
{% if instance.ad or instance.user == request.user or request.user.is_authenticated == False %}
```

I recently added `request.user.is_authenticated == False` in this condition and now it is not working. It should fire if the user is not logged in.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Try printing out `request.user.is_authenticated` (e.g. `{{ request.user.is_authenticated }}`) to make sure it's actually `false` ;)

Comment: Also, this shouldn't make a difference in functionality but you can simplify `request.user.is_authenticated == False` by replacing it with `not request.user.is_authenticated`

Comment: Yep mistake on my end it's working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you wouldn't need to prefix user with request. in your templates.

I.e. `{% if user.is_authenticated == False %}`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're using the correct [template processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/#django-template-context-processors-request) so that the `request` variable is actually accessible from within a template. You can also print out variables, such as `request.user.first_name`, etc., to make sure they're what you expect them to be.